# Communication between Android app and server on computer

Tags: java, android, sockets, server

I would like to make an Android app that would send and receive plain-text messages from a server on a computer. I tried using sockets but I can't send messages back to the server, only receive them.

Is there a built-in way to communicate with a computer?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd use a [Web Service](http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/android-webservice-tutorial/) for this purpose.

> A web service is a standard used for exchanging information between
>   applications or systems of heterogeneous type. Software applications
>   written in various programming languages and running on various
>   platforms can use web services to exchange information over Internet
>   using http protocol.

With a Web Service, you can write methods that your application consume. These methods can return or take in parameters just like any other method, and transporting this information using SOAP. Below is an example of an Android app that consumes a Web Service. In this case, the Web Service converts Celcius to Fahrenheit.

```
private final String NAMESPACE = "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/";
private final String URL = "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx";
private final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/CelsiusToFahrenheit";
private final String METHOD_NAME = "CelsiusToFahrenheit";
private String TAG = "PGGURU";
private static String celcius;
private static String fahren;

public void getFahrenheit(String celsius) {
    //Create request
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
    //Property which holds input parameters
    PropertyInfo celsiusPI = new PropertyInfo();
    //Set Name
    celsiusPI.setName("Celsius");
    //Set Value
    celsiusPI.setValue(celsius);
    //Set dataType
    celsiusPI.setType(double.class);
    //Add the property to request object
    request.addProperty(celsiusPI);
    //Create envelope
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
            SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    //Set output SOAP object
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    //Create HTTP call object
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

    try {
        //Invole web service
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        //Get the response
        SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
        //Assign it to fahren static variable
        fahren = response.toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

In above example, the Web Service is located on a server with the address http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx. You can click the link to consume the Web Service in your browser.

As previously stated, a Web Service can be written in various programming languages. [Here's](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/308359) an example of how to write one using C#. This Web Service can be consumed languages not only restricted to C# (as the Java example above).